# Why does this declaration not work

Tags: c, pointers

In `int (*x)[10];` `x` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s

So why does this code not compile:

```
int arr[3] ;

int (*p)[3] =arr;
```

But this works:

```
int  arr[3];

int (*p)[3] =&arr;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`arr` is an expression that evaluates to an `int*` (this is the famous 'arrays decay to pointer' feature).

`&arr` is an expression that evaluates to a `int (*)[3]`.

Array names 'decay' to pointers to the first element of the array in all expressions except when they are operands to the `sizeof` or `&` operators.  For those two operations, array names retain their 'arrayness' (C99 6.3.2.1/3 "Lvalues, arrays, and function designators").

Comment: +1: I would also point out that, although of a different type, both expressions return the same pointer address.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for exactly the same reason as:

```
int i;
int* pi = i; // error: no conversion from int to int*
```